# Facebook App for research rejected

Tags: facebook

I am a PhD student in Computer Science. I am collecting data about public pages that users follow once they have enrolled in our study. For this my app requires the "user_likes" permission. Our study is approved by the Institutional Review Board (IRB) at my university and users will explicitly consent to us collecting this information. However, my app was rejected in review because of the following feedback:

> Your screencast doesn't show how the use of this permission directly improves the user experience in your app. Unfortunately, we also weren't able to determine this from testing your app manually.
>   All permissions data must be visibly used within your app. We do not accept permission requests for data that you may decide to use later.

Since our app is collecting data once the user has consented, it doesn't make any sense that we would be able to show any of this in our app. Is Facebook pretty much preventing researchers from using the API at all? Since research applications will rarely be an operating app that improves user experience.

It seems like all these restrictions will prevent any further academic research with consenting users.

Please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to use the Facebook API you have to follow the rules in Facebook Platform Policy

Answer (score 0):

Facebook's Graph API is meant towards developers and businesses that want to leverage the social graph in their products.

For research data, I suggest you contact Facebook's academic collaborations: https://research.fb.com/programs/research-collaborations/